# Identify SMD component, possibly SOT23 charge controller labeled LBTL

Tags: identification, surface-mount, charger

What is this SMD? I know it may be a SOT23 charge controller, but I’m looking to find the pin-out. It looks like it’s labeled as LBTL and I can’t find the manufacturer.

[image]

Comment: The package looks like SOT-23-8, not SOT-32 (which is a through-hole package).

Comment: I apologize I meant sot 23, but it only has 5 pins. The only SMD to dip board I had has 8 contacts, so I’m just utilizing the 5 it’s soldered to.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the marking is L8 (el-eight) and not LB (el-bee).
With this, the only smd sot-23-5 I could find were the following (from RICOH):

RN5RG - voltage reg
R1121N281A - also a voltage reg
RN5RY381A - Dc/Dc converter

MArking L8T revealed Seiko Instruments S-1122B34MC-L8TTFG

hope that helps !